# How can I change my Supermicro server's BIOS logo?

Tags: boot, bios, supermicro, korean

I already changed server's splash logo, but I still can't change logo that is shown while the system is initializing.

The logo I have changed:
[image]

The logo I can't change:
[image]

Comment: If SM has a tool to do it, then yes you can, if not then you cannot.

Comment: thanks for the answer :)

Comment: i solved it just open file with wordpad and delete that '#'word